# Why isn't tiered pricing being applied to configurable products?

Tags: magento-1.8, tierprice, shopping-cart

I'm new to Magento here and I'm trying to understand why tiered pricing is applied to simple products but not the configurable product that they're associated with. I've done a ton of googling on the topic and I've found a couple of extensions that claim to do what I need done but they're old and it's not clear if they're compatible with Magento 1.8. Also, all of the forum topics I find about this seem to be dated 2008/2009 so I'm not finding anything current on this topic. It's frustrating.

Simply put, how can I apply the tiered prices for simple items to the configurable item that they're associated with?

Answer (score 2):

From experience, you'll need to use an extension that would inherit the prices of the simple products.

Two such extensions that I've used for this are BCP and Amasty Color Swatches.

However, going on this basis, you need to be aware that you need to set the tier prices for all simple products. It may be the case that this is not suitable for your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Configurable product prices are determined in `\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Price.php`
and as you've already figured out, is independent of the simple products prices.

An alternative if possible is grouped products, which still adhere to the simple products tiered prices.

Otherwise, you can use one of the extensions mentioned by JamesAllwood or this one which is quite popular. 
https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple 
Do not use the one from magento connect.
I've not used it with 1.8, but there is a review saying it works. YMMV.

Comment: I would not recommend using `OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts`, because it does a whole lot of stuff and has not been developed any further since years. This most probably causes problems at some point.

Comment: This fork is actually much better maintained and resolved a lot of the issues of compatibility since the old OrganicInternet repo was left to die:

https://github.com/obigroup/magento-configurable-simple

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to resolve this issue is by using this extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/spranks-configurabletierprices.html

This applies the logic that even if 2 or more different simple products within a Configurable are purchased it will add the number of these bought together and apply the tiered pricing.

Works right up to CE 1.9

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! Although this (= my) extension still uses the tier price information from the configurable product. Hence, I am not sure if this solves the problem of the OP.

Comment: @Simon you are absolutely correct here, my apologies to the poster as this answer does not directly relate and resolve the issue posted, in my haste I had missed this. Also your extension is an excellent fix for an almost ridiculous issue for tiered pricing so thank you for that Simon.