# What's the simplest way to handle special pricing and wholesale tiered pricing?

Tags: price, shopping-cart-price-rules

So here are the requirements:

- Support for special pricing (we do sales a couple times a year)
- Support for wholesale pricing by customer group
- Support for configurable and simple products.

Seems simple enough, but here are some of the complications:

Initially I used Tiered Pricing to accomplish wholesale pricing - works great for breaking down pricing by customer group and quantity.  But it's [broken](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/15372/41) for configurable products.

So I did something similar to what [Simple Configurable Products](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple) does which is just to always add the Simple product to the cart whenever a customer adds a configurable to the cart.

But then I stumbled onto another problem, which is that in our case - and I'm not sure if this is normal for wholesale workflows or not - we need wholesale pricing to kick in *across different products*.  So for example, someone buys 4 units of Product A and 2 units of Product B, since they're buying more than 6 units and are in the wholesale customer group, they need to get the wholesale discount.

So at this point I switched over from doing Tiered Pricing to simply using Shopping Cart Price Rules to accomplish the same discount based off of the product category and the customer group.

But now I have a problem when a product has a special price, because now the wholesaler will get their wholesale discount stacking with the special price, which we don't want.

It would be great if I were using Tiered Pricing b/c Magento already has that case handled natively - it picks the lower of the two if both Special Prices and Tiered Prices are used.  But I can't do that because of the above issues.

So what I'm planning to do now is simply use Shopping Cart Price Rules for the sale pricing and avoid using Special Prices altogether.  The downside there is that I won't get my nice original price / final price per product that I can use to show the original price striked-out with the sale price in bold.

Is there a simpler way of implementing the business logic I'm getting at?  And/or on a less technical and more business level (that's allowed here right?) - is any of this business logic unnecessary / overkill for standard wholesale workflows?

Comment: Have you thought about the Amasty module that handles special rules and discounts?

Comment: http://amasty.com/special-promotions-pro.html

Comment: Hi Kalen, shucks, you referenced an old comment of mine! As it happens, I'm working on a project that is almost identical to what you're trying to achieve, and as it also happens, I'm using the extension suggested by Brent. I'll keep you updated. Also playing around with http://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html which has great tiered price functionalities.

Comment: @JamesAllwood yes I did!!  That comment was actually very helpful for me previously :)  Just realized I had never +1'd that answer - shame on me.  Done.  Very interesting that you're doing something similar - I'll check out the amasty module!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need tiered pricing to be SKU agnostic and work with configurable products? This offering seems to fit the bill - http://www.webshopapps.com/us/extras/tiered-pricing-across-multiple-products.html - That said, I've dealt with many store owners who struggle to adapt their preexisting business logic to Magento. Sometimes it might be worthwhile to consider changing business logic to fit within Magento, especially for a brick and mortar just starting out in ecommerce.

Comment: Thanks @pspahn!  I hadn't found that module in my searches previously.

Comment: @kalenjordan could you solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're having around tiered pricing and configurables is quite a common one.

An example of what you're describing is as such:

Configurable A - Has 2 simple products, Simple A and Simple B

Tiered pricing for Configurable A is Buy 2 and save 10%.

But if 1 Simple A and 1 Simple B is bought, no discount is applied.

The very simple solution is to use this free extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/spranks-configurabletierprices.html

With this you would get the required functionality so:

Configurable A - Has 2 simple products, Simple A and Simple B

Tiered pricing for Configurable A is Buy 2 and save 10%.

1 Simple A and 1 Simple B is bought, system add's 1 & 1 simples within the configurable bought. Discount is applied.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice thanks!  I'll need to dig into that a bit further so I can mark this as the answer.  I ended up finding a solution so this isn't an immediate priority for me at the moment.