# Tire price not calculating at the cart page

Tags: magento-1.9

One product has tire price option, but when i click 'add to cart' button, I am  getting wrong 'unit price' and 'subtotal' at the Shopping cart page. Please see the both images:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this a configurable product? If so, you might find an answer here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15367/why-isnt-tiered-pricing-being-applied-to-configurable-products