# Magento 2: Display tier prices in tabular format

Tags: magento2, tierprice

How can we display tier prices in tabular format in product page ? Like below...

```
Qty    Price
1- 10  50
11-20  40
...
```

Comment: Are you looking something like this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108107/tire-price-not-calculating-at-the-cart-page

Comment: It is for Magento 1.9. I asked question regarding Magento 2. I already mentioned it in question title.